# How to check the value belongs to an interval in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, intervals

I have an input field

```
<md-input-container ng-if="gpa.grade_type==2"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="gpa.grade_percent" aria-label="Grade">
</md-input-container>
```

I want to check the gpa.grade_percent "percent_grade_from": 93 - "percent_grade_to": 96, value in JSON in which interval it fits
so that I have to show the interval related scale in the next field.

```
<td>
    <span ng-bind="gpa.grade_scale"></span>
</td>
```

JSON :

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "letter_grade": "A",
    "percent_grade_from": 93,
    "percent_grade_to": 96,
    "scale": "4.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "4.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.9"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "letter_grade": "A-",
    "percent_grade_from": 90,
    "percent_grade_to": 92,
    "scale": "3.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.9",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "letter_grade": "B+",
    "percent_grade_from": 87,
    "percent_grade_to": 89,
    "scale": "3.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "letter_grade": "B",
    "percent_grade_from": 83,
    "percent_grade_to": 86,
    "scale": "3.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "letter_grade": "B-",
    "percent_grade_from": 80,
    "percent_grade_to": 82,
    "scale": "2.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.0",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "letter_grade": "C+",
    "percent_grade_from": 77,
    "percent_grade_to": 79,
    "scale": "2.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "letter_grade": "C",
    "percent_grade_from": 73,
    "percent_grade_to": 76,
    "scale": "2.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "letter_grade": "C-",
    "percent_grade_from": 70,
    "percent_grade_to": 72,
    "scale": "1.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "1.9",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "letter_grade": "D+",
    "percent_grade_from": 67,
    "percent_grade_to": 69,
    "scale": "1.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "1.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "1.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "letter_grade": "D",
    "percent_grade_from": 65,
    "percent_grade_to": 66,
    "scale": "1.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "0.1",
    "honors_gpa_to": "1.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "0.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "letter_grade": "E/F",
    "percent_grade_from": 0,
    "percent_grade_to": 65,
    "scale": "0.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "0.0",
    "honors_gpa_to": null,
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "0.0",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "letter_grade": "A+",
    "percent_grade_from": 97,
    "percent_grade_to": 100,
    "scale": "4.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "4.5",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "5.0",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "5.0"
  }
]
```

Comment: So what did you try so far? You can create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.gpa = {grade_percent:68};
    
    var data = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "letter_grade": "A",
    "percent_grade_from": 93,
    "percent_grade_to": 96,
    "scale": "4.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "4.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.9"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "letter_grade": "A-",
    "percent_grade_from": 90,
    "percent_grade_to": 92,
    "scale": "3.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.9",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "letter_grade": "B+",
    "percent_grade_from": 87,
    "percent_grade_to": 89,
    "scale": "3.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "4.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "letter_grade": "B",
    "percent_grade_from": 83,
    "percent_grade_to": 86,
    "scale": "3.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "3.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "4.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "letter_grade": "B-",
    "percent_grade_from": 80,
    "percent_grade_to": 82,
    "scale": "2.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.0",
    "honors_gpa_to": "3.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "letter_grade": "C+",
    "percent_grade_from": 77,
    "percent_grade_to": 79,
    "scale": "2.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "3.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "letter_grade": "C",
    "percent_grade_from": 73,
    "percent_grade_to": 76,
    "scale": "2.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "2.3",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "3.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "letter_grade": "C-",
    "percent_grade_from": 70,
    "percent_grade_to": 72,
    "scale": "1.7",
    "honors_gpa_from": "1.9",
    "honors_gpa_to": "2.2",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.4",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.7"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "letter_grade": "D+",
    "percent_grade_from": 67,
    "percent_grade_to": 69,
    "scale": "1.3",
    "honors_gpa_from": "1.6",
    "honors_gpa_to": "1.8",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "2.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.3"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "letter_grade": "D",
    "percent_grade_from": 65,
    "percent_grade_to": 66,
    "scale": "1.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "0.1",
    "honors_gpa_to": "1.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "0.1",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "letter_grade": "E/F",
    "percent_grade_from": 0,
    "percent_grade_to": 65,
    "scale": "0.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "0.0",
    "honors_gpa_to": null,
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "0.0",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "letter_grade": "A+",
    "percent_grade_from": 97,
    "percent_grade_to": 100,
    "scale": "4.0",
    "honors_gpa_from": "4.5",
    "honors_gpa_to": "4.5",
    "ap_ib_gpa_from": "5.0",
    "ap_ib_gpa_to": "5.0"
  }
];
    $scope.find = function(){
      $scope.gpa.grade_scale = (data.filter(function(x){
        return x.percent_grade_from <= $scope.gpa.grade_percent && x.percent_grade_to >= $scope.gpa.grade_percent;
      })[0] || {}).scale;
    }
    $scope.find();
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="gpa.grade_percent" aria-label="Grade" ng-change='find()'>
    <br/>
    <span ng-bind='gpa.grade_scale'></span>
</div>
```